# How to get websocket data as state in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, next.js

My task is to set a websocket and get its data with onMessage() and assign it to redux state. But I don`t know how to implement it. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to dispatch you actions inside your event listener:

```js
// Listen for messages
socket.addEventListener('message', (socketData) => {
  //event is data passed from socket to you

  //dispatch your data accordingly
  store.dispatch({
    type: 'Read the docs',
    payload: socketData
  })
});
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, thanks alot. I also should get lots of real time data. Is it ok to create seperate websocket for each of them to implement it?

Comment: Yes you can do that by separating your events emitted from back-end and listen to them in front-end accordingly